# Halmos square breaks with XCharter/ensuremath

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, amssymb, xcharter

I am trying to define a `\QED` command that invokes `\square` (defined in `amssymb`. Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage[scaled=0.96, sups, scosf, osf]{XCharter}

\RequirePackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XCharter-Math.otf}
\def\QED{\ensuremath{{\square}}}

\begin{document}

\QED
$\square$

\end{document}
```

This compiles to the following:

[image]

where `$\square$` is displayed correctly but not `\ensuremath{{\square}}`. Why?

Comment: `Missing character: There is no ∎ (U+220E) in font [XCharter-Roman.otf]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unicode-math` defines `\QED` to be U+220E ∎ but it does its definition `\AtBeginDocument` so over-writes your definition of `\QED` and the chosen font does not have the character.

```
\documentclass{article}

\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{amssymb}
\RequirePackage[scaled=0.96, sups, scosf, osf]{XCharter}

\RequirePackage[warnings-off={mathtools-colon,mathtools-overbracket}]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XCharter-Math.otf}
\AtBeginDocument{\def\QED{\ensuremath{{\square}}}}

\begin{document}


X
\QED
$\square$


\end{document}
```